# Insert custom variable in $http post request header or body

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, http, post

In my project, I already have AngularJS service that inserts desired object using $http.post as follows:

```
function insertObject(object, callback) {
        $http.post(apiUrl, object).success(function (data) {
```

"object" is set in corresponding AngularJS controller and sent to my service like:

```
objectServices.insertObject(object, function (data) {
```

According to this, "object" is sent through $http post request body. What I need, is to send one additional variable inside this $http request. Actually, this variable should be URL (route), with which the controller works. 
I can't change this object structure (to attach new property to it, which would hold URL info etc.) because  `$http.post(apiUrl, object)` matches corresponding backend API Controller method that takes exactly this object as parameter (this object is entity). 
I tried something like this:

Declare variable that will hold URL info:

```
var url = window.location;
```

And attach it to $http.post header like:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common["currentUrl"]= url;
```

where "currentUrl" is supposed to be key and url is value.

Also tried something like:

```
$http.post(apiUrl, object, headers: { 'currentUrl': url })
```

and on backend side, inside corresponding API Controller HttpResponseMessage method tried to extract it from request header as:

```
Request.Headers.Single(x => x.Key == "currentUrl").ToString();
```

but it didn't work. Please, can someone explain how to send custom data inside http post request and tell me what wrong is with my try?

**EDIT: Content of Request.Header on backend side is:**

[image: Content of Request.Header on backend side is:]

Comment: Have you inspected your request to see if your custom header is included in the HTTP request sent ?

Comment: Yes of course. It didn't contain my custom key-value pair:

"currentUrl" : url

I refactored code according to @Jagrut's suggestion and it didn't work still.

Answer (score 0):

While attaching the variable: 
`$http.defaults.headers.post.currentUrl = url;`

When making the call, you missed the braces:
    `$http.post(apiUrl, object, {headers: { 'currentUrl': url }})`

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work. On the backend side, when I debug "Request.Headers" object, there is no

'currentUrl' : url  

key:value pair.